Resetting Logic Pro user profile settings
While trying to deal with Logic Pro audio input issues, which is related to user profile settings,  gpt-d a script to reset the profile (subject to improve). But still, it did not resolve the problem. Version 11.0.1. Switching to another user profile work well with the same device setup.
Is there anything else to add?
#!/bin/bash

# Reset Logic Pro user profile settings

# Function to remove directories and files
remove_item() {
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        sudo rm -rf "$1"
        echo "Removed: $1"
    else
        echo "Not found: $1"
    fi
}

# Remove Logic Pro preferences
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.logic10.plist"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.logic.pro.cs.plist"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.logic.pro.midi.plist"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.logic.pro.audio.plist"

# Remove Logic Pro Application Support files
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Logic"

# Remove Logic Pro Caches
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Caches/com.apple.logic10"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Caches/AudioUnitCache"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Caches/com.apple.audiounits.cache"

# Remove Logic Pro saved state
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.logic10.savedState"

# Remove Audio preferences
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Preferences/Audio"

# Remove Logic Pro container (if it exists)
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.logic10"



# Remove any .plist files related to Logic Pro

sudo find "$HOME/Library/Preferences" -name "*logic*.plist" -delete

# Reset audio and MIDI settings
defaults delete com.apple.audio.AudioMIDISetup

defaults delete com.apple.audio.CoreAudio


# Restart the audio service
sudo killall coreaudiod

# Remove user-specific plugin components, VST, and VST3 plugins
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST"
remove_item "$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3"

echo "Logic Pro user profile settings have been reset."
echo "Please restart your computer to ensure all changes take effect."

